# Why is methoxide a strong base?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Why is methoxide strong base? In case of halogens, I get why one is weak base, and one is strong base, but in the case of ones with oxygen, this seems to be hard to figure out.

Answer (score 8):

Methoxide ($\ce{CH3O-}$) is the conjugate base of methanol. Methanol is very weak acid (e.g. its dissociation constant is very small), so its conjugated base is very strong.

Comment: Further reasoning can be that there is no delocalization for the free electron pair of oxygen because of the way the orbitals are oriented, so that makes it less stable.